# ZSH Ruby command not found

Tags: ruby, bash, zsh

I'm pretty inexperienced with terminal type stuff besides the most basic commands, I recently switched from Bash to ZSH with in oh-my-zsh.  I'm trying to make an executable ruby script at usr/bin/test.rb. For what it's worth, I never tried this with bash so I have no idea if its zsh specific.

```
$~  test.rb
/usr/bin/test.rb: line 2: puts: command not found

$~  ruby test.rb
ruby: No such file or directory -- test.rb (LoadError)
```

and my .zshrc file:

```
export ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
export PATH="/Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-       2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/jason/.rvm/bin:.git/safe/../../bin:.git/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/jason/.rvm/bin"
```

.

```
~  which ruby
/Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
```

test.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
 puts 'test!'
```

Comment: try chmod +x test.rb and then run again.
If that didn't work try chmod 777 test.rb and run again.

Comment: What does the shebang line in test.rb read? Are you sure that test.rb exists in the directory that you're invoking it from?

Comment: also please post the output of the following command: which ruby

Comment: @royskatt, I already ran chmod

Comment: Say `ruby /usr/bin/test.rb` please

Comment: But really, don't put stuff in usr

Comment: Very seriously, what @matt said, "don't put stuff in `/usr`. It'd be really good for you to read about how *nix systems work, even at a basic level. `/usr` is where commands go that affect the system, but, `/usr/bin` is for system-wide stuff installed by the system. `/usr/local/...` is for stuff installed by the user. But, for scripts you're writing and testing, put them somewhere in your home directory, which should be somewhere in `/home/your_account`. I have a collect-all directory called `development` in my home directory for my coding efforts.

Comment: Thinking about it further, to install *anything* in `/usr/bin` you had to do it as root, either by using `sudo` or `su`, but, in either case, *STOP IT* until you understand why and what you're doing. Use either [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) to create a Ruby in a sandbox, allowing you to more safely experiment until you know more about how to use a *nix system. Your future self will thank you profusely.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feed back, I'll move it in with the rest of my dev stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$~  test.rb
/usr/bin/test.rb: line 2: puts: command not found
```

This is probably because your script is missing an essential line, often called a "pound-bang line" or, more simply, a "bang line", which tells the operating system what program to use to execute the rest of the file. Typically, for Ruby scripts, it looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

and *MUST* be the first line in the file. When the OS opens the file, it looks for `#!` and, if it sees those, launches the executable at the path given, and passes the script to it. That's basic script execution on a *nix system, and applies to sh/Bash/Perl/Python/Ruby and any number of other executable applications on a *nix system.

```
ruby test.rb
ruby: No such file or directory -- test.rb (LoadError)
```

I suspect the second failed because you weren't in the `/usr/bin/` directory when you executed that command. Ruby tried to run the script but couldn't find it in the local/current directory.

I'm not trying to be cruel, but, as a programmer, you'll spend a *huge* amount of time at the command-line, especially so if you are programming in C/C++, Perl, Ruby, Python, or any non-IDE based language. You have to learn how the OS works otherwise disasters of varying sizes and shapes await you, so, in parallel to learning a language you need to learn how to use, and administer, your OS. You don't have to be a power-user or administrator, but you have to know enough to understand good instructions from ones that don't apply, or are just plain-wrong.

Comment: If someone using `Rvm`, then what path should go in the *bang* path ?

Comment: But he said that his script _has_ a shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`

Comment: He added that after the fact.

Answer (score 3):

Well I was facing the same problem, I had ruby & rails installed but I couldn't run them on ZSH

The answer is so simple
Just Add the following lines to .zshrc

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Then run

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

After that to check if ruby & rails are found by ZSH run

```
ruby --version
rails --verison
```