# Ruby script: shebang with absolute path to ruby not working

Tags: ruby, environment-variables, shebang

I am using Mac OS X. I have two versions (2.1.5 and 2.0.0) of Ruby installed. The former installed at /another/.path/to/ruby (there is a dot before "path" to mimic the fact that the path contains a dot-headed directory in between), in addition to the default system one (version 2.0.0) at /usr/bin/ruby. I used rbenv to install Ruby.

After I manually set the PATH environment variable so the default ruby command will be found in another directory: /another/.path/to/ruby. Now I check

```
which -a ruby
```

It is using correct ruby first, as output.

```
/another/.path/to/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Now I create a script, rbs, with the first line of shebang specifying the ruby to use.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts 'hey there'
```

Then I run

```
./rbs
```

it outputs 'hey there'. Good. Meanwhile, the Ruby is using the correct version.

```
/usr/bin/env ruby --version
```

as well as

```
ruby --version
```

both output 2.1.5. So it does great job to use the new version.

However, here is where the problem occurs: now I update rbs file to be:

```
#!/another/.path/to/ruby
puts 'hey there'
```

Note that I updated the shebang to use the absolute path to the desired ruby. then I run

```
./rbs
```

It outputs:

```
./rbs: line 2: puts: command not found
```

which is too weird;

but if I run

```
ruby ./rbs
```

it outputs 'hey there' as normal. It looks like the shebang works perfect using /usr/bin/env ruby, but not for absolute path for the newly install ruby?

Why is this? Is there a way to fix it so the updated script can still work by typing the following?

```
./rbs
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is `./rubyscript` in your `./rbs` output?

Comment: Sorry, a typo. I will update it. It is just the ./rbs file.

Comment: Does `/another/.path/to/ruby rbs` work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `puts: command not found` message indicates that your script is not being run by Ruby, but by the shell instead.  So first, I would double-check your shebang line's syntax and path.

Second, note that rbenv uses shims that dynamically find and run the right version of `ruby` (and associated programs like `gem`, etc).  But the shims are scripts, and scripts *can't themselves be shebang interpreters*; you have to find and use the actual path to the ruby executable (as output by `rbenv which ruby`).

On the other hand, since `/usr/bin/env` *is* an executable, you can always use something like `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`, which will work even if the `ruby` it finds in the path is itself a script.

Comment: This is an excellent answer! Thanks, Mark. Your point that shims are scripts that can't themselves be shebang interpreters makes the perfect sense.

Answer (score -1):

I can't comment, (otherwise I'd add as a comment) but I think its worthwhile to add that the

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

MUST be the first line of the file. This tripped me up for a while.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974431/zsh-ruby-command-not-found?rq=1)